# Dreams - false awakening - explanation in shastras

Tags: vedas, puranas, dream

Hinduism says lot about dreams and it's meaning. About thuriya state etc. But I want to know about false awakening.
False awakening happens when u feel that u have risen from sleep and do morning routines until u see something unusual and then u realize u r still in sleep (REM sleep) and force urself to wake up. What is this state called as or has this been explained anywhere in shastras Or puranas.
Eg I wake up from sleep and open the door to get the milk packet. But then there is lots of tree fallen in the lawn. I tried to get through the mess and then I realize this can't be true and force myself to wake up.

Comment: Lucid dreams or probably something like that. It sounds like a sleep paralysis, not being able to wake up when realizing sleeping. Mandukya Upanishad talks about different states and the knowledge of self. But it doesn't discuss complex sleep problems requiring medical interventions.